# What's the difference between Sparkconf and Sparkcontext?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've encountered a problem with `pyspark` when I've made `Import Pyspark from Sparkcontext` but I found that it can be imported from sparkconf as well, I'm asking what's the difference between those two spark class libraries.

Comment: I post this question cuz I could not find an answer somewhere. I don't understund why this question get downvotes

Comment: I can see a few problems with the question at first glance. You said you _encountered a problem_ but you didn't mention what it was and what you were trying to do when you encountered it.Then you mentioned _"when I import it from"_, but you didn't tell what did you mean by _it_. If you just want to know all the differences between `SparkContext` and `SparkConf`, then it is too broad to answer here. Those are two separate classes. And BTW, I didn't downvote it.

Comment: when I said "encountered a problem", I've refered to an other problem that I can't asked in the same post (one post for one question). and just for you, it's a problem when I run in zeppelin : `%spark.pyspark from pyspark import SparkContext`. The second thing about "when I import it from", I think it's obvious that I refer to pyspark lib. and if you think that's too broad so I don't think there is more effecient way to ask this question other way. thank you BTW

Answer (score 2):

Sparkcontext is the entry point for spark environment. For every sparkapp you need to create the sparkcontext object. In spark 2 you can use sparksession instead of sparkcontext.

Sparkconf is the class which gives you the various option to provide configuration parameters.

```
Val Conf = new sparkConf().setMaster(“local[*]”).setAppName(“test”)
Val SC  = new sparkContext(Conf)
```

The spark configuration is passed to spark context. You can also set different application configuration in sparkconf and pass to sparkcontex

Answer (score 0):

**SparkConf** is a configuration class for setting config information in key value format

**SparkContext** is the main entry class for establishing connection to the cluster.

Implementation of SparkConf-->

class SparkConf(object):

```
def __init__(self, loadDefaults=True, _jvm=None, _jconf=None):
    """
    Create a new Spark configuration.
    """
    if _jconf:
        self._jconf = _jconf
    else:
        from pyspark.context import SparkContext
        _jvm = _jvm or SparkContext._jvm
```

In this SparkContext is imported in the constructor, so you can pass the sparkContext. Similarly in SparkContext we have sparkConf as parameter so that you can pass sparkConf to it.

Thus you are setting values of configuration in both the ways.